# tower of hanoi using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

how does each stack in a tower of hanoi problem how is it executed line by line i can't quite understand the way that each stack gets created???

```
public class TowerOfHanoi {

    public static void towerOfHanoi(int disks, char source, char auxiliary, char destination) {
        if (disks == 0) {
            return;
        }

        towerOfHanoi(disks - 1, source, destination, auxiliary);
        System.out.println(source + " " + destination);
        towerOfHanoi(disks - 1, auxiliary, source, destination);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        towerOfHanoi(4, 'a', 'b', 'c');
    }
}
```

Comment: What about it *do* you understand?

Comment: in which order each stack is created and how does it actually work when u look deep how does each disk is shifted???\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work:

```
private static void hanoiTower(int n, char from_rod, char to_rod, char aux_rod){
    if(n == 1){
        System.out.println("Move disk 1 from rod " +  from_rod + " to rod " + to_rod);
        return;
    }
    hanoiTower(n-1, from_rod, aux_rod, to_rod);
    System.out.println("Move disk " + n + " from rod " +  from_rod + " to rod " + to_rod);
    hanoiTower(n-1, aux_rod, to_rod, from_rod);
}
```